# Wifi Control Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, wifi, windows-phone-8.1

I'm building a Windows Phone ( and 8.1 App, which uses a Wifi connection to syncronize some data with a database.

My problem is that I have several hotspots. Can I force my application to use a predefined hotspot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have no control over WiFi with the current API.

Comment: Hmmn :( Not the answer I'd hoped for.

Comment: The problem is my Windows Phone uses 30 secs to switch form one Wifi network to an other. Can this problem be solved?  Either fromthe source code or an other way.